# How to always use ignore-platform-reqs flag when running composer?

Tags: php, configuration, composer-php, hhvm

On my local machine, I have php v7.0.3. A project of mine has a dependency on php v5.5.

So as expected, a simple run of `composer install` crashes:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ~5.5 but your PHP version (7.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I know I can ignore the platform via:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

yet I often forget to add the flag. Yet since the application runs inside a docker container, a mismatching php can install the dependencies just as fine.

So I am wondering if there is a way to make my local composer always assume `--ignore-platform-reqs` in order to not having to type it.

I like to avoid setting an alias and have it work on composer config level.

Comment: Could you show me how you do that please? I only have 1 laravel package where I can't install it for the life of me. Yeah, I know i can ignore the platform reqs but it seems like you know how to!

Comment: @Eduardo Without context it's hard to know what you want to achieve. You can ask as follow-up question linking to this one. It's best you have a reproducable and minimal example of your problematic `composer.json` and local php version.

Comment: No worries I was able to fix my issue, thanks for replying you sir are good man! :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's recommended to [fake the PHP version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform), rather than to ignore platform requirements. Add:

```
"platform":{"php":"5.5"}
```

to your `~/.composer/config.json` or use `composer config -g -e` to edit it.

An example of a config to fake the PHP version and an extension:

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform":{
            "php": "8.1",
            "ext-bcmath": "8.1"
        }
    }
}
```

More options about the config's platform section can be found in the [Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform).

**UPDATE:**
starting from v2.3.0 you can use environment variables.
Please see [Yakatz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73146605/1110423)

Comment: Could you please provide a full `config.json` example? It seems that for me the config is currently ignored.

Comment: hmm, just tested it on ubuntu.  `composer show --platform` confirms *Package overridden via config.platform (actual:...*, and when I fake php as 3.2, `composer update` yelds *- This package requires php >=5.2 but your PHP version (3.2) does not ....*

Comment: I just realized that I have  both a requirement on php `~5.5` and `5.4`, so I guess that I am in a deadlock when choosing between the two. Yet what I found particular interesting is that `composer config -e` open the `composer.json` file of the project  instead of the `config.json` of composer's home.

Comment: Sorry, typo, as always =(. It is global config of course:  `composer config -g -e`.  The one which is user-specific. How do you resolve this deadlock on other environments?

Comment: We are using hhvm :D Not ideal, but it seems that composer does not check Plattform

Comment: If you want this tied to your specific project or to work without having composer installed globally (like me), you can place the config block in your composer.json file

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It also allows configuring extensions that are missing. For example when making a quick demo project that uses moneyphp (which requires ext-bcmath), and you just quickly use the composer Docker image to setup some dependencies. Just add "ext-bcmath": "8.2" to the platform config.

Answer (score 40):

A new feature in **Composer v2** allows you to selectively ignore platform requirements.

`composer install --ignore-platform-req=php`

Composer already has a `--ignore-platform-reqs` option (notice the s in `reqs`), but it ignores all platform requirements, including PHP version, extensions `(ext-*)`, and composer-plugin-api.

The new `--ignore-platform-req` option can be used to set specific requirements that Composer can ignore.

Answer (score 19):

Composer [now supports](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-ignore-platform-req-or-composer-ignore-platform-reqs) (as of version 2.3.0) checking an environment variable to set `--ignore-platform-reqs`.

Create an environment variable `COMPOSER_IGNORE_PLATFORM_REQS=1` to ignore all or `COMPOSER_IGNORE_PLATFORM_REQ=something` to ignore `something` as a requirement.

Comment: This is should be the best answer as of 2022

Answer (score 11):

You can add `alias composer="composer --ignore-platform-reqs"` to your `.bash_profile` but it will break commands that don't recognize this option (eg. `composer outdated`).

Personally I have:

```
alias composer="composer --ignore-platform-reqs"
alias composer_orig="/usr/local/bin/composer"
```

Because most of the time I want `--ignore-platform-reqs`, but still I can use `composer_orig` each time I see

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>
> The "--ignore-platform-reqs" option does not exist.

Comment: you can bypass alias by running `\composer`.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, update composer.bat (under C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin) and add `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the composer command.

To update, you may open text-editor as administrator > Ctrl + O > Open composer.bat

If you don't want the change it globally for all your projects, create a new .bat file and use it in PHPStorm > Settings > composer