# Extension gd is missing from your system - laravel composer Update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gd

I newly install Dompdf in Laravel Project via Composer (`composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`). After enter the Command Terminal Reply Following Errors.

```
Problem 1
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.7.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.7.0 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.7.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How to Solve this Error

I already Installed GD using Following comment. `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` and also Apache Server Restarted. My Laravel Version is 5.3 and Ubuntu Version is 14.04

Comment: sudo apt-get install your-php-version-gd did it for me.

Answer (score 129):

I have installed php7, I did the following to solve exactly the same error

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xsl
```

Comment: Just doing `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Work like charm :
`sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.2-xsl`

Comment: Nice!! It depends on the PHP version that we have installed

Comment: Thanks very much. this was the missing piece. I also had to add 

`sudo apt-get install php-curl` too.

Comment: worked for me without php version. Like `sudo apt-get install php-gd`. You can do all the same

Comment: what about `yii2`?

Answer (score 65):

For **php-8**, just locate your `php.ini` file and uncomment the line `extension=gd`
Below is a picture guide for those using **Xampp** and **Windows**

**Step 1: Open php.ini or locate it in your machine (C:/xampp/php/php.ini)**

[image: Open php.ini or locate it in your machine (C:/xampp/php/php.ini)]

**Step 2: Uncomment the line extension=gd by removing the semicolon**

[image: Uncomment the line extension=gd by removing the semicolon]

**Step 3: Save your file and restart your services**

[image: Save your file and restart your services]

Answer (score 38):

If you are working in PHP version 5.* then you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

And if you are working in PHP version 7.* then you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Hope it will work...

And if you are working in PHP version 7.2 then you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd... it worked for me
```

Comment: Here's the CentOS 7 stanza when using SCL and PHP 7.1: `yum install rh-php71-php-gd`.

Comment: This worked for me on php 7.2.24 (sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd)

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php7.2-gd... man I do not miss PHP what garbage.

Answer (score 24):

Open your **php.ini** and uncomment this line:

`;extension=php_gd2.dll`

Answer (score 20):

It may not be enabled for php-cli, you can enable like this;

```
sudo phpenmod gd
```

UPDATE

I guess, you are using ppa:ondrej php package (5.6), which is confusing you with default ubuntu 14.04 php package (5.5.9).

To install php 5.6 gd library from ppa:ondrej, you should use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

Comment: after Enable GD Display Following Errors. WARNING: Module gd ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/5.6/mods-available

Comment: Hera is solution of your problem http://laravel.io/forum/05-30-2014-mcrypt-php-extension-required

Comment: I do you suggested Method. but i got same error. @VaheGalstyan

Comment: Which php version you use?

Answer (score 16):

PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Feb  5 2020 16:50:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

For Php 7.4.2

1. sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
2. sudo phpenmod gd

Answer (score 14):

Before installing the missing dependency, you need to check which version of PHP is installed on your system.

```
php -v
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

In this case it's php7.2. `apt search php7.2` returns all the available PHP extensions.

```
apt search php7.2
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.2/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)

libphp7.2-embed/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  HTML-embedded scripting language (Embedded SAPI library)

php-all-dev/bionic,bionic 1:60ubuntu1 all
  package depending on all supported PHP development packages

php7.2/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all
  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)

php7.2-bcmath/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Bcmath module for PHP

php7.2-bz2/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  bzip2 module for PHP

php7.2-cgi/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)

php7.2-cli/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language

php7.2-common/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  documentation, examples and common module for PHP

php7.2-curl/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  CURL module for PHP

php7.2-dba/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  DBA module for PHP

php7.2-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Files for PHP7.2 module development

php7.2-enchant/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Enchant module for PHP

php7.2-fpm/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)

php7.2-gd/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  GD module for PHP

php7.2-gmp/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  GMP module for PHP

php7.2-imap/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  IMAP module for PHP

php7.2-interbase/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Interbase module for PHP

php7.2-intl/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Internationalisation module for PHP

php7.2-json/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  JSON module for PHP

php7.2-ldap/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  LDAP module for PHP

php7.2-mbstring/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  MBSTRING module for PHP

php7.2-mysql/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  MySQL module for PHP

php7.2-odbc/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  ODBC module for PHP

php7.2-opcache/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Zend OpCache module for PHP

php7.2-pgsql/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  PostgreSQL module for PHP

php7.2-phpdbg/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (PHPDBG binary)

php7.2-pspell/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  pspell module for PHP

php7.2-readline/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  readline module for PHP

php7.2-recode/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  recode module for PHP

php7.2-snmp/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  SNMP module for PHP

php7.2-soap/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  SOAP module for PHP

php7.2-sqlite3/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  SQLite3 module for PHP

php7.2-sybase/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Sybase module for PHP

php7.2-tidy/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  tidy module for PHP

php7.2-xml/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
  DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP

php7.2-xmlrpc/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP

php7.2-xsl/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all
  XSL module for PHP (dummy)

php7.2-zip/bionic-updates,bionic-security 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64
  Zip module for PHP
```

You can now proceed to installing the missing dependency by running:

`sudo apt install php7.2-gd`

Answer (score 13):

if you are working in PHP version 7.2 then you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm working on php 8.0.9, and I just uncomment this on `php.ini` in `xampp/php/php.ini` directory.

from

```
;extension=gd
```

to

```
extension=gd
```

and it's work normal again

Answer (score 5):

For php 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

Cheers!

Comment: I got this: 
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-gd'

Comment: Add ppa repository and try: 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php and sudo apt-get update and then the above command.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is quite simple.

In your php.ini, just uncomment the line `extension=php_gd2.dll` (or .so extension for unix systems.)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: That this solution worked does not mean that it is the best. The package/sdk you are installing actually requires that but you are ignoring it

Answer (score 4):

As of Composer 2.0 on Arch, I use: `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd`

Eg:

```sh
php composer install -n --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd
```

Eg: (to ignore multiple requirements)

```sh
php composer install -n --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd --ignore-platform-req=ext-ldap
```

Ignoring Composer requirements may be necessary because Composer may return false warnings on dependencies that are already properly installed and enabled, consider [this Arch forum article](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163591):

> I have installed php-gd and uncommeted extension=gd.so in /etc/php/php.ini as the wiki says

Thanks for this answer on a related Question, [How to always use ignore-platform-reqs flag when running composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67033761/10343144)

Comment: Good answer. This will get you going. Thanks @Jesse Steele. So many answers here and none explain WHY? Because CLI and web server may be using different `php.ini` files! Different extensions are enabled. You rarely need GD for command line tasks so it's not in that `php.ini`. Also, if you are using the Docker-based container for Composer, you could be running Composer under a completely different version of PHP. Just ignore the reqs as Jesse says.

Comment: You saver of my life!!!!! Lost all morning but when I ignored the warning package installed!

Answer (score 2):

Using Manjaro(Arch) Linux:

```
$ sudo pacman -S php-gd
```

In file /etc/php/php-ini, add the line:

```
extension=gd.so
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows :
Uncomment this line in your php.ini file

```
;extension=php_gd2.dll
```

If the above step doesn't work uncomment the following line as well:

```
;extension=gd2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip
```

Use your version of php. Like here I used 7.4

Comment: my system os is ubuntu 20.04, i first installed `sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd` its  then your command,` sudo apt-get install php7.4-zip`. then composer install worked as normally

Answer (score 1):

First Check your php version

```
sudo php -v
```

Then install php gd package of relevent version.

```
sudo apt-get install php${version}-gd
```

Finally run

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

Unbuntu

```
sudo apt install php-gd
```

Answer (score -1):

On CentOS 7, try running following command:

```
sudo yum install php72u-gd.x86_64
```

Answer (score -1):

in docker I found a same problem, even after
"rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php"
then
"apt update"
"apt install php7.4-gd"

"php composer.phar update"
error " ..... ext-gd ....."
so my solution is direct using php7.4
"php7.4 composer.phar update"

and its work. I dont know why.

Answer (score -2):

On Local or Xampp in windows
go to : C:\xampp\php\php.ini

uncomment `extension=gd`

Answer (score -3):

It may help you

`apt install php-xml`

`systemctl restart apache2`

From [reference](https://wiki.iphoster.net/wiki/PHP_-_Ubuntu_-_ext-dom_-_the_requested_PHP_extension_dom_is_missing_from_your_system) here, you may learn in brief.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please share more details. If the error message tells you that `ext-gd` is missing, how could installing the XML extension resolve that problem?

Answer (score -3):

```
PHP VERSION - 7.3.21
WAMP SERVER

// use below command to fix ext-gd issue
// work for me
composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Comment: If the gd extension is missing, this command won't install it magically