# Laravel error when installing simple-qrcode library

Tags: laravel

I need to add QR features in my project so I found siple-qr Library, but when I run

```
composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
```

it says

```
Using version ^4.2 for simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode ^4.2 -> satisfiable by 
simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode[4.2.0].
    - simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode 4.2.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your 
system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: PHP gd extension is missing or not enabled.[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42889350/6274211) SO answer for reference.

Comment: sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: which os are you using? The method in the link is for linux/ubuntu.

Comment: My advice, use bacon/bacon-qr-code for adding qr codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and search for `extension=gd`. Remove the `;` in front of the found line. Save the changes, restart XAMPP (not sure if necessary) and you're ready to go.

```
composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode
```

Sometimes it is necessary to change the `extension_dir` variable to `extension_dir = "ext"` on windows systems. Also in the `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, edit the **composer.json** file.

```
"require": {
    ....
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~4"
},
```

then run the following command in the console: **composer update**

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode:4.2 --with-all-dependencies
```

first of all,

determine the version (4.2) and updated all the dependencies after changing the extention_dir

from  extension_dir='\xampp\php\ext' to extension_dir='C:\xampp\php\ext'

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that the **Simple-QRCode** package requires the **PHP GD extension**, which is currently missing or not enabled on your system.

Here are the steps to enable the GD extension:

> **1.** Open your PHP configuration file (**php.ini**). In your case, it seems to be located at `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.
>
> **2.** Search for the following line in the php.ini file: `;extension=gd` Remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line to
> uncomment it: `extension=gd`
>
> **3.** Save the php.ini file and restart your web server (e.g., Apache) for the changes to take effect.

After enabling the GD extension, you should be able to install the Simple-QRCode package without any issues.

Comment: **Reminder:** Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)