# Can't install PhpSpreadsheet by composer

Tags: composer-php, codeigniter-4, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to add PhpSpreadsheet to my CodeIgniter 4 project.

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

and I am getting this errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.24 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.24.0].
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.24.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

How to fix it?

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "codeigniter4/appstarter",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "CodeIgniter4 starter app",
    "homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4 || ^8.0",
        "codeigniter4/framework": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-fileinfo": "Improves mime type detection for files"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/Database/Migrations/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\Support\\": "tests/_support"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "phpunit"
    },
    "support": {
        "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
        "source": "https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4",
        "slack": "https://codeigniterchat.slack.com"
    }
}
```

@edit:

This post help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615935/7683760