# failed to install maatwebsite/excel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, maatwebsite-excel

So i want to install maatwebsite/excel, and and I've tried several things but to no avail. can someone help me. I use laravel v 9 and php v 8.1

```
> Gymnastiar@LAPTOP-NEA31346 MINGW64
> ~/Documents/Gymnastiar/Project/YamahaL8 $ composer require
> maatwebsite/excel Using version ^3.1 for maatwebsite/excel
> ./composer.json has been updated Running composer update
> maatwebsite/excel Loading composer repositories with package
> information Updating dependencies Your requirements could not be
> resolved to an installable set of packages.
> 
>   Problem 1
>     - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by
> phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
>     - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by
> phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.24.0].
>     - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.24.0].
>     - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.24.0].
>     - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.24.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
>     - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].
> 
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>     - C:\xampp\php\php.ini You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode. Alternatively, you can
> run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore
> these required extensions. You can also try re-running composer
> require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require
> maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or
> "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you ne
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extension gd is missing from your system - laravel composer Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384644/extension-gd-is-missing-from-your-system-laravel-composer-update)

Comment: "I've tried several things but to no avail" - please name some of them, especially those that were already part of that error message

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to php.ini file in `C:\xampp\php`
2. Search this `;extension=gd`
3. Remove `;` then restart the xampp
4. Add `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.0"` to `"require"` in `composer.json` file
5. Run `composer update maatwebsite/excel`

**Update:** If you encounter this issue on Ubuntu-Debian OS, simply execute this command to install the php-gd extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-gd // for php8.1
sudo apt-get install php8.2-gd // for php8.2
```

Comment: any explanation on why?

Comment: @Harvir Because the error message states "require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system".

Answer (score 3):

1. First add "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1" at **composer.json** file on your project

   ```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
        "illuminate/support": "^5.5|^6|^7|^8",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^1",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"
    },
   ```
2. Now make sure you update the composer

   ```
   composer update
   ```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The error message lets me think that this requirement was already added through `composer require`. Adding it manually to the configuration does not do anything different

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).