# Error in installing barryvdh/laravel-snappy in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, barryvdh

I want to export a PDF file and I have run the command:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy
```

and I encountered this error:

[image: encountered error image]

I tried running the following command but it still doesn't work:

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error states the extension `gd` is missing. You may check out a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384644/extension-gd-is-missing-from-your-system-laravel-composer-update

Comment: Prefer text to image, it turns the question better searchable.

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that you are missing the `gd` PHP extension. This extension is required by the `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` package, which is a dependency of the `maatwebsite/excel` package.

To install the `gd` extension, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your PHP configuration file (usually `php.ini`).
2. Find the line
   that says `extension=gd`. If it is commented out (preceded by a
   semicolon), uncomment it.
3. Save the file and restart your PHP server.

Once the `gd` extension is installed, you should be able to run the
`composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy` command without any
errors.

If you are still having problems, you can try running the following command:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy:2.1.1
```

This will install a specific version of the package, which may be more compatible with your system.

Once the package is installed, you can follow the instructions in the documentation to start using it.

Here are some additional tips for troubleshooting the error message:

- Make sure that you are running the `composer require` command from
  the root directory of your Laravel project.
- Try running the command
  again with the `--no-dev` option. This will prevent Composer from
  installing development dependencies, which may be causing the
  conflict.
- If you are using Vagrant, make sure that the `gd` extension
  is installed and enabled on your guest machine.