# How to tell composer to ignore php version for a specific package?

Tags: composer-php

I can't seem to install a package because I need to use php 5.6 and the minimum is 7.

I tried

```
composer require mopo922/laravel-treats --ignore-platform-reqs

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package mopo922/laravel-treats at any version matching your PHP version 5.6.32.0
```

Then I temporary removed the platform requirement from the composer file and successfully installed but now I can't do "composer update"

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.4 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.3 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.1 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.0 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mopo922/laravel-treats v2.0.4 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.6.32) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for mopo922/laravel-treats ^2.0 -> satisfiable by mopo922/laravel-treats[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4].
```

Any way composer can ignore a specific package?

Comment: How do you expect to use this package on PHP 5.6 if it requires PHP 7.0?

Comment: it's a small package and the feature I want is php 5.6 compatible(because it supports eloquent 5.4 which is php 5.6 compatible) as far as I know, see mopo922/laravel-treats

Answer (score 4):

I see three possibilities here:

1. extract the feature you need from `mopo922/laravel-treats` and use it directly in your project. If its just a small feature it shouldnt have a big impact to not include it by composer. Its better than messing up the version constraints imho.
2. use `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`
3. use the [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) config option and just fake that you have PHP 7.
   see: [How to always use ignore-platform-reqs flag when running composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273522/how-to-always-use-ignore-platform-reqs-flag-when-running-composer)
   This however could lead to other problems, f.e when installing new packages which use the PHP7 constraint although you actually dont support it. So be carefully with it.
   This is basically the same as removing the platform requirements when your dev machine has PHP 7.